# Add custom fee to recurring total WooCommerce subscription

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, woocommerce-subscriptions

```
function add_woocommerce_stripe_fee() {
    if ( ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) ) || ! is_checkout() )
        return;
 
    $chosen_gateway = WC()->session->chosen_payment_method;
        
    if ( 'stripe'  ==  $chosen_gateway ) {
        $fee = (WC()->cart->cart_contents_total * .035) +0.35;       
        WC()->cart->add_fee( 'Stripe Fee', $fee, false, '' );
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees','add_woocommerce_stripe_fee' );
```

It is not adding for recurring cart total but works fine for the normal products ( not working for WooCommerce Subscription products ). Any help would be greatly appreciated. Is this possible.?

Answer (score 4):

I provided a more in-depth answer on a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54833189/5217184).

Long story short try adding this:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_subscriptions_is_recurring_fee', '__return_true' );
```

And check out the [Woocommerce doc](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/subscriptions/develop/recurring-cart-fees/) that provides some examples that may help you.

Comment: In which version this hook is introduced?