# WooCommerce Subscriptions Missing Interval Text

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, woocommerce-subscriptions

I am testing fees with WooCommerce Subscriptions and have noticed a missing feature that support is unable to help with.

When adding a 'recurring fee' to the checkout using their sample code (below), the plugin does not add the subscription interval after the fee price.

*Example:*

*Actual:*  FEE: £5.00

*Expected:*  FEE: £5.00 / month

I first came across this problem by trying to add a fee using WooCommerce Extra Product Options by Themecomplete, however, I've noticed even using the code below from the WooCommerce plugin developer guide, it does not work for any recurring fees.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', 'add_recurring_postage_fees', 10, 1 );
function add_recurring_postage_fees( $cart ) {
if ( ! empty( $cart->recurring_cart_key ) ) {
    $cart->add_fee( 'Postage', 5 );
}
}
```

I can see within WooCommerce Subscriptions (file: recurring-totals.php) that the plugin recognises the recurring fee:

```
<?php foreach ( $recurring_cart->get_fees() as $recurring_fee ) : ?>
    <tr class="fee recurring-total">
        <th><?php echo esc_html( $recurring_fee->name ); ?></th>
        <td><?php wc_cart_totals_fee_html( $recurring_fee ); ?></td>
    </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Developer Guide: https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/subscriptions/develop/recurring-cart-fees/

As can be seen in their screenshot, the words '/ month' is missing from the fee in their example: [Recurring Fees Image >](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/recurring-only-cart-fees.png)

It needs to be dynamic based on the subscription interval, not just a predetermined phrase. Does anyone have knowledge of WooCommerce Subscriptions and Fee's to be able to identify the problem?

Comment: [Check this out](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49668525/1117368). It may be useful

Comment: Thanks, tried this but it's not what I'm looking for. The recurring fees are being added correctly, they just done show the subscription interval after the fee.

Answer (score 0):

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_subscriptions_is_recurring_fee', '__return_true' );

add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', 'add_recurring_postage_fees', 10, 1 );

function add_recurring_postage_fees( $cart ) {

    if ( !empty( $cart->recurring_cart_key ) ) {

        $intervals = explode( '_', $cart->recurring_cart_key );
        $cart->add_fee( 'Postage/' . end( $intervals ), 5, false, '' );
    }
}
```

[image]

Try this as a possible solution.

Comment: That's a step closer. I am looking for this to work with fees set by plugins as well, not just code to set a fee.

Comment: The other way you mentioned is not possible as there is no hook in woocommerce.

Comment: I know. Been trying different options but it doesn't look possible. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than set a fee, I'm looking for something that works with fees from any source such as other plugins. Something that replaces the recurring fee price string would work better... (I know this doesn't work, just an idea):

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_totals_fee_html', 'sab_custom_fee_interval' );
function sab_custom_fee_interval( $price ) {
return $price . $cart->recurring_cart_key;
}
```

But I do not know how **$cart->recurring_cart_key** works within the subscriptions plugin. Still playing around with this...